# i would like to redirect to an page when my query is succesful

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to link to page when the query is succesfull the query is executed by a press on a button.
Now it instant links to `klantvoltooid.php`.

```
$verplicht = array('voornaam','achternaam','email','telefoonnummer','woonplaats');

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    if(in_array(trim($key),$verplicht)){
        if(empty($value)){
            $error = true;
        }
    }
}   

if(isset($error) && $error = true) {
    header("location:../nieuweklant.php");
    echo "U bent een veld vergeten intevullen";
} else { // else execute query
    $nieuweklant  = "INSERT INTO klanten (voornaam,achternaam,tussenvoegsel,email,telefoonnummer,woonplaats,nieuwsbrief) VALUES ('$voornaam','$achternaam','$tussenvoegsel','$email','$telefoonnummer','$woonplaats','$nieuwsbrief')";
    mysql_query($nieuweklant) or die(mysql_error());
    //stuurt de medewerker naarde voltooi pagina
    header("location:../klantvoltooid.php");
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: For starters, don't use `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated now. It also looks like you don't have any idea of SQL injection concerns. Finally, as per @deceze's comment - what's your question? The code should function without problem...

Comment: now it instant redirect to klantvoltooid.php but it never has execute the query.

Comment: ther is an error in your check, replace `if(isset($error) && $error = true)` with `if(isset($error) && $error == true)`, notice the **==**

Answer (score 1):

It was already noted that this line:

```
if(isset($error) && $error = true)
```

needs to be this (== for comparison):

```
if(isset($error) && $error == true)
```

**It's also worth mentioning that this code:**

```
 echo "U bent een veld vergeten intevullen";
```

**will never execute because the browser will have already re-directed.**